# Juju Ceilometer-Agent is not reporting about nova-compute

Tags: juju

I have deployed both ceilometer and ceilometer-agent and added relationship between them. After deployment I can see the resource usage for network(neutron), glance, cinder but I cannot see the information for nova-compute.

But it is instructed that ceilometer-agent should deployed in every compute node but with juju its not possible to deploy it on specific compute node.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The [ceilometer-agent charm](http://manage.jujucharms.com/charms/precise/ceilometer-agent) is a subordinate charm; you should be able to run:

```
juju add-relation ceilometer-agent nova-compute
```

This should automatically deply ceilometer-agent to all units running nova-compute.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, but is it the case that when I run an instance then I can see the parameters related to nova compute?